# Need a similar functionality like WaitForPageToLoad in MonkeyTalk

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, iphone

Is there any **similar** function/ **command** in **MonkeyTalk**, like **WaitForPageToLoad** which is in Selenium, that lets me specify the script to **wait for a screen to render** before moving ahead? I checked MonkeyTalk's language reference but could not find a way. Also searched for this issue on Google but it didn't help me much.

The iOS native app i'm testing takes some time to load and open up the home screen after login. After recording the event flow using MonkeyTalk, and running the test script, the script always fails because it does not wait for the home screen to render and moves ahead to identify the UI element being clicked by the user, which it does not find. Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonkeyTalk waits and retries automatically for **all** commands. By default it retries for 2s, if you want to wait longer, just put a bigger number in the timeout column in the MonkeyTalk IDE.  For example, 5000 would retry for 5s.  See [MonkeyTalk Spec: Command Timings](http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk/documentation/monkeytalk-spec/command-execution) for details.

Comment: Thankyou! It worked!
I just had to use %thinktime and %retrydelay. %timeout was not needed.

Comment: Also I want to know if I can override the Tap function through MonkeyTalk's JavaScript library?
If that is so, then i can set the thinktime and retrydelay as a default value in the Tap function's parameters before executing the script.